# SKTextureAtlas gets overridden by declaration of second SKTextureAtlas

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Whenever I create and define two variables as type SKTextureAtlas they rewrite each other. Here is my initial creation of my two SKTextureAtlas

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var idle = true

    var TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureAtlasIdle = SKTextureAtlas()
```

Later on in my code I assign a folder of images to each atlas. If I comment out the second atlas my animation works, but when I define the two as shown below my animation overlaps and plays frames from cat_walk even though it is told to only play cat_idle

```
    TextureAtlasIdle = SKTextureAtlas(named: "cat_idle")

    for i in 1...TextureAtlasIdle.textureNames.count{

        let Name = "\(i).png"
        TextureArrayIdle.append(SKTexture (imageNamed: Name))
    }

   TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "cat_walk")
```

This is how I start my cat_idle animation. I don't start the cat_walk animation

```
aN.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with:self.TextureArrayIdle, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
```

I'm trying to find out why this line of code is causing my two different animations to overlap.

```
TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "cat_walk")
```

Comment: your code works fine. you might have done something wrong with Texture Atlas folders and its contents. can you provide screenshot of your atlas folders and contents?

Comment: I think you have named your both atlas folder's contents as **1.png, 2.png** ... and so on. try to change **cat_idle.atlas** folders contents as **idle1.png, idle2.png**.. and so on. and also make sure to rename **cat_walk.atlas** folders' images like **walk1.png** and so on

Comment: This looks like a complete waste of resources,  why are you not building your atlas via XCAssets

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just had to rename all of the images distinctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Texture Atlas** is kind of a sprite sheet for your game. Your approach is not right for accessing atlas images for the game. modify your ***for loop*** like below:

```
  for i in 0..< 8 {
        let texture:SKTexture = TextureAtlasIdle.textureNamed(String(format: "%i", i+1))
        TextureArrayIdle.insert(texture, at:i)
    }
```

Every time you access your atlas folder, use this for loop procedure. i have used static **8** number in for loop, it would be your sprites count. There is a simple game called [Desert Run](https://github.com/novalain/desert-run) in github. please check this out for more clarification.

**NB:** your cat's images naming must start with **1.png** 
if you want to run the ***for loop***

Comment: this is Swift, you can just do `TextureAtlasIdle.textureNamed("\(i+1)"))`